# Save Jags/ Winbugs output in R

Tags: r, output, winbugs, jags

I'm running Jags/ Winbugs in R, which works fine, but I can't save the output to a text or csv file (either would work)

```
TEST.sim<- jags(data=jags.data, 
                parameters.to.save=jags.params, 
                n.iter=200000,jags.seed=123, 
                model.file="~/Documents/ARRModel.txt")
```

What I need is a way to save the output that comes up when I enter:

```
print(TEST.sim)
```

When I try write.table it gives the following error:
    cannot coerce class '"bugs"' into a data.frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using library `R2jags` and function `jags()` then function `print()` makes table of statistics that are stored in list element `BUGSoutput` and sublist `summary`. You can access those data directly and store as other object (or just use directly in function `write.table()`) and then write to text file.

```
jag.sum<-TEST.sim$BUGSoutput$summary
jag.sum

                mean         sd        2.5%         25%         50%          75%        97.5%     Rhat n.eff
alpha     19.6399640 1.22982919  17.1888046  18.8401629  19.6391880  20.45108889  22.03860486 1.001312  4100
beta1     -0.1063905 0.01755548  -0.1409861  -0.1180097  -0.1064871  -0.09469226  -0.07198614 1.001028 18000
beta2     -0.1857631 0.03667742  -0.2573464  -0.2103279  -0.1860142  -0.16155874  -0.11304929 1.001138  7700
deviance 192.6742580 3.02780455 188.9038177 190.4371154 192.0046398 194.13875526 200.28772929 1.001252  4800

write.table(x=jag.sum,file="out.txt",sep="\t")
```